# Transferring values between two columns in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
p q
0.5 0.5
0.6 0.4
0.3 0.7
0.4 0.6
0.9 0.1
```

So, I want to know, how can I transfer greater values to p column and vice versa for q column (Transfering smaller values to q column) like this:

```
p q
0.5 0.5
0.6 0.4
0.7 0.3
0.6 0.4
0.9 0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use apply function :

```
df[['p','q']] = df.apply(lambda x: [x['p'],x['q']] if x['p']>x['q'] else [x['q'],x['p']],axis=1,result_type='expand' )
```

Answer (score 3):

You could store some conditional series with `np.where()` and then apply them to the dataframe:

```
s1 = np.where(df['p'] < df['q'], df['q'], df['p'])
s2 = np.where(df['p'] > df['q'], df['q'], df['p'])
df['p'] = s1
df['q'] = s2
df
Out[1]: 
     p    q
0  0.5  0.5
1  0.6  0.4
2  0.7  0.3
3  0.6  0.4
4  0.9  0.1
```

You could also use `.where()`:

```
s1 = df['p'].where(df['p'] > df['q'], df['q'])
s2 = df['p'].where(df['p'] < df['q'], df['q'])
df['p'] = s1
df['q'] = s2
df
```

---

I tested the execution times over varying rows from 100 rows to 1 million rows, and the answers that require passing `axis=1` can be `10,000 times slower!`:

1. Erfan's numpy answer looks to be the fastest executing in milliseconds for large datasets
2. My `.where()` answer also has great performance that keeps the time to execute in milliseconds (I assume `np.where() would have a similar outcome.
3. I thought MHDG7's answer would be the slowest, but it is actually faster than Alexander's answer.
4. I guess Alexander's answer is slow, because it requires passing `axis=1`. The fact that MGDG7's and Alexander's answer is row-wise (with `axis=1`), it means that it can slow things down tremendously for large dataframes.

As you can see a million row dataframe was taking minutes to execute. And, if you had a 10 million row to 100 million row dataframe these one-liners could take hours to execute.

---

```
from timeit import timeit
df = d.copy()

def df_where(df):
    s1 = df['p'].where(df['p'] > df['q'], df['q'])
    s2 = df['p'].where(df['p'] < df['q'], df['q'])
    df['p'] = s1
    df['q'] = s2
    return df


def agg_maxmin(df):
    df[['p', 'q']] = df[['p', 'q']].agg([max, min], axis=1)
    return df


def np_flip(df):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.flip(np.sort(df), axis=1), columns=df.columns)
    return df


def lambda_x(df):
    df = df.apply(lambda x: [x['p'],x['q']] if x['p']>x['q'] else [x['q'],x['p']],axis=1,result_type='expand')
    return df


res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[20, 200, 2000, 20000, 200000],
    columns='df_where agg_maxmin np_flip lambda_x'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.concat([df]*i)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        print(stmt, d.shape)
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=1)

res.plot(loglog=True);
```

[image]

Comment: @Siavash no problem, by the way I noticed that each time you upvoted a solution you then accepted that as solution. I'm not sure if you intended to do that, but you should accept what you think is the "best solution". In my opinion, Alexander's solution is the best solution, but what matters is what you think the best solution is. When there are multiple competing solutions and you accept one, it's good to give a one-sentence or a couple of words about why. If you do not know what the best solution is, then just say you don't know and picked one randomly.

Comment: Thank you for your notice! actually, both Alexander and MhDG7 solutions are the best solutions. However, the Alexander solution is simple and probably faster than MhDG7 solution; I believe that the MhDG7 solution may be more understandable for beginners.

Comment: @Siavash out of my own curiosity, I tested the performance of the four answers. The key takeaway for me is that operations that require passing `axis=1` will significantly slow down operation on larger dataframes and can take minutes or hours versus milliseconds or seconds for vectorized solutions with non-row-wise operations. For some reason, I thought Alexander's answer would still be fast, but it is a good lesson that passing `axis=1` is dangerous for performance -- 10,000 X slower! You might as well `for-loop` through the dataframe.

Comment: Good analysis. I updated my answer with a solution that appears to be faster than any presented so far.

Comment: @DavidErickson in Erfan answer there is a problem. when we have more than two columns (for example three columns) Erfan's solution transfers the greatest values to the first column and vice versa for the 3rd while I want to transfer values between only two columns. So, your solution is the fastest way regarding your diagram!

Comment: I would tag @Erfan . I am better with pandas and not very good with numpy.

Comment: @Siavash I would mention on his answer.

Comment: @DavidErickson yes, your way is the fastest. however, we did not test it in a parallel way!

Comment: @Siavash what do you mean by that we didn't test in a parallel way?

Comment: @DavidErickson I mean you tested solution (time of different solutions) without multithreading (using multiple CPUs). Definitely, employing multi-threads can decrease the time of analysis.

Comment: @Siavash , yes, you could multi-thread, but why would you if you if you don’t need to? Multi-threading should be a last resort. The different solutions are milliseconds versus minutes, so there is no reason to do so. And what if you are writing thousands of lines of code? Are you going to multi-thread each and every time you write row-wise functions or are you just going to vectorize? Imagine having to multi-thread dozens of times in your Code, all to still be outperformed by vectorization.  It’s generally accepted in pandas/numpy that vectorized methods should be the first choice if possible.

Comment: @DavidErickson As you mentioned, in this case we do not need to use multi-thread. However, evaluating time of analysis can make sense when we have a big data and multithreading can be accelerative for this.

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.sort` to sort over the horizontal axis ascending, then flip the arrays over `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.flip(np.sort(df), axis=1), columns=df.columns)
```

```
     p    q
0  0.5  0.5
1  0.6  0.4
2  0.7  0.3
3  0.6  0.4
4  0.9  0.1
```

Comment: @Erfan In my answer, I tested the different answers out of curiosity. This one was the winner for all numbers of rows tested. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), pass a list of functions (`max` and `min`) and specify `axis=1` to have those functions be applied to the columns row-wise.

```
df[['p', 'q']] = df[['p', 'q']].agg([max, min], axis=1)

>>> df
     p    q
0  0.5  0.5
1  0.6  0.4
2  0.7  0.3
3  0.6  0.4
4  0.9  0.1
```

Simple solutions are not always the most performant (e.g. the one above).  The following solution is significantly faster. It masks the dataframe for where column `p` is less than column `q`, and then swaps the values.

```
mask = df['p'].lt(df['q'])
df.loc[mask, ['p', 'q']] = df.loc[mask, ['q', 'p']].to_numpy()
>>> df
     p    q
0  0.5  0.5
1  0.6  0.4
2  0.7  0.3
3  0.6  0.4
4  0.9  0.1
```

Comment: Nice! +1 Or simply `df = df.agg([max, min], axis=1)`; however, in the actual dataframe there are likely other columns, which is why you are specifying. I think this is the simplest and best answer.

Comment: Correct, I am assuming the dataframe would contain additional columns.

Comment: @Alexander this turned out to be the slowst in terms of performance. It's because of passing `axis=1` -- making it row-wise?

Comment: @Alexander not sure if you saw my update answer but from 100 to one million