# How to merge rows in pandas for unordered pair of colums?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have rows in my dataframe as follows-

```
     Team 1          Team 2         Winner       winner_count
0   Afghanistan     Australia     Australia             1
19    Australia   Afghanistan     Australia             1
```

I want to merge this both rows into one and sum winner_count such that -

```
     Team 1          Team 2         Winner       winner_count
0   Afghanistan     Australia     Australia             2
```

this should be my output.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of rows in your dataframe, I would try to avoid a row-wise function that passes `axis=1`. You can see the performance impact from a very similar question that I answered earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64298461/6366770) :

```
s1 = np.where(df['Team 2'] > df['Team 1'], df['Team 1'], df['Team 2'])
s2 = np.where(df['Team 2'] < df['Team 1'], df['Team 1'], df['Team 2'])
df['Team 1'] = s1
df['Team 2'] = s2
df = df.groupby(['Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Winner'])['winner_count'].sum().reset_index()
df
Out[1]: 
        Team 1     Team 2     Winner  winner_count
0  Afghanistan  Australia  Australia             2
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one on for size:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Initialise test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team 1': ['A', 'B'], 'Team 2': ['B', 'A'], 'winner_count': [1, 1]})

# Get the smallest team name (alphabetically)
df['First'] = df[['Team 1', 'Team 2']].min(axis=1)

# Get the largest team name (alphabetically)
df['Second'] = df[['Team 1', 'Team 2']].max(axis=1)

# Groupby the teams to sum winner_counts
df = df[['First', 'Second', 'winner_count']].groupby(['First', 'Second']).sum().reset_index()
```

It seems a bit of an inefficient solution, so see if anyone else comes up with a nicer approach.

Answer (score -1):

IMO the solution should deal with the possibility of having more than two teams in the dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Team1": ["Afghanistan", "Australia", "Australia", "Belgium", "Afghanistan"],
                   "Team2": ["Australia", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan","Belgium"],
                   "Winner": ["Afghanistan", "Australia", "Australia", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"],
                   "winner_count": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
                   })
```

I would first identify each combination of teams through a new columns "Teams":

```
df.loc[:,"Teams"] = df.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(sorted([x["Team1"],x["Team2"]])), axis=1)
```

Then it is possible to group by combination of teams and place the winning team on top of each group:

```
group = df.groupby(by=["Teams","Winner"]).agg({
    "Teams":"first",
    "Team1":"first",
    "Team2":"first",
    "winner_count":"sum"}).sort_values(by=["winner_count"], ascending=False)
```

Having already the "teams" column IMO it doesn't matter which of the two teams is Team 1 or Team 2. Duplicates are removed:

```
group.drop_duplicates(subset="Teams", inplace=True)
```

It is possible to remove also the MultiIndex ["Teams", "Winner"] through:

```
group.reset_index(level=1, drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Hereby the results dataframe group (without the index "Teams"):

```
+-------------+------------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|   Winner    |         Teams          |   Team1   |    Team2    | winner_count |
+-------------+------------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|             |                        |           |             |              |
| Australia   | Afghanistan, Australia | Australia | Afghanistan |            2 |
| Afghanistan | Afghanistan, Belgium   | Belgium   | Afghanistan |            2 |
+-------------+------------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```